# How to find GTK version in PHP-GTK2?

Tags: php, gtk, gtk2

This one is driving me nuts.  According to GTK's site, there exists GTK_MAJOR_VERSION, GTK_MINOR_VERSION, and GTK_MICRO_VERSION constants.  However, none of these work:

echo GTK_MAJOR_VERSION;
echo GtK::MAJOR_VERISON;
echo Gtk::GTK_MAJOR_VERSION;
etc

Also, Gtk::check_version(2,12,0) always fails even though I have a higher version.

I'd like to simply get the actual version number and not rely on check_version, which seems unreliable.

How can I do this?
I need to do it within PHP, platform independent.

Answer (score 0):

Found a code example:

```
static public function GetGtkVersion()
{
        $sVersion = Gtk::get_version() ;
        $sVersion = str_replace('Gtk','',$sVersion) ;
        $sVersion = str_replace('GTK','',$sVersion) ;
        $sVersion = trim($sVersion) ;

        list($nPriVer,$nSecVer,$nThdVer) = explode('.',$sVersion) ;
        $aVersion = array($nPriVer,$nSecVer,$nThdVer) ;
        return $aVersion ;
}
```